# Hash delete_if in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to remove key-value pairs from a hash whose value is less than the highest key-value pair's value in the hash. Example: If my hash is `{:Jan => 3, :Feb =>4, :Mar =>4}`, I'd want to remove the `:Jan => 3` entry. I am attempting `delete_if` with a comparison to no avail.

```
def highestvalue(myhash)
  myhash.delete_if { |k,v| v < v}
  print myhash
end

months = {:Jan => 3, :Feb =>4, :Mar =>4}
highestvalue(months)
```

Comment: How is `v` supposed to be smaller than itself?

Comment: You shouldn't be `print`ing inside the method.  It should just return the pairs with the highest value.  Having it modify the hash to do so is very surprising behavior that I would not recommend.  Given the name of the method, I would expect it to return the key,value pairs corresponding to the highest key value without modifying the original hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def highestvalue(myhash)
  max = myhash.values.max
  myhash.delete_if { |k, v| v < max }
end
```

Comment: Same as `myhash.reject! { |k, v| v < max }`, except `reject!` returns `nil` if no changes are made.

Comment: I don't think I'd put something destructive in a method with this name...

Comment: @MarkThomas, Would you be happy with a different name, or do you have bias against destructive methods? I admit to the later, and here would prefer `reject` (no `!`), allowing the user to have `myhash = highestvalue(myhash)`, if so desired.